# Angular 2 update class with setTimeout

Tags: angular, ng-class

I'm trying to add a class to an element and remove it after a certain time using `setTimeout`.

**Component**

```
export class setClass implements OnInit {
  className: string = ''

  setClassName(newClass) {
    this.className = newClass

    setTimeout(function () {
      this.className = ''
    }, 1500)
  }

  constructor() { }

  ngOnInit() {
  }
}
```

**Template**

```
<div>
    <img src="img/1.png" alt="" [ngClass]="className">
    <button (click)="setClassName('foobar')">Set new class</button>
</div>
```

I can see the function adds the class name 'foobar' but it stays forever. I'm expecting this function to remove the newly added after 1500ms.

Please help me fix this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your this line `this.className = newClass` the `this` is pointing to the component but the `this` inside timeout is pointing to the window use ES6 to ignore this

```
setTimeout(() => {
  this.className = "";
}, 1500);
```

Or store instance of `this` to `vm`

```
let vm = this;
setTimeout(function() => {
  vm.className = '';
}, 1500);
```

both are working fine.

Answer (score 0):

'this' is not defined in your timeout function because of function scope and you'll not be able to use it. You can use an arrow function like this:

```
setTimeout(()=> {
      this.className = ''
    }, 1500)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<div>
    <img src="img/1.png" #image alt="">
    <button (click)="setClassName('foobar')">Set new class</button>
</div>

export class setClass implements OnInit {
  className: string = ''
  @ViewChild("image") image ;
  setClassName(newClass) {
    this.image.nativeElement.classList.add(newClass)
    let self = this;
    setTimeout(function () {
      self.image.nativeElement.classList.remove(newClass)
    }, 1500)
  }

  constructor() { }

  ngOnInit() {
  }
}
```

Comment: I suspect you will get cannot call classList of undefined

Comment: I updated my solution @yurzui   , it works fine.

Comment: 'this.image' will still be undefined in the setTimeout function

Comment: sorry see the update

Answer (score 0):

Change it to the code below and it will work. Also, have a plunker https://plnkr.co/edit/oEfZOW?p=preview that shows it working

```
let $this = this;
setTimeout(function () {
    $this.className = '';
}, 1500);
```